# Calculate the difference between two subqueries

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 subqueries which give me a result consisting of dates.
I would like to calculate the difference between them.

For example:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF(
  DAY,
  (SELECT MAX(invoices.date) FROM invoices WHERE invoices.orderno = odH.orderno),
  (SELECT min(history.date) FROM history WHERE history.orderno = odH.orderno)
) ...
```

Comment: 1. Which bit is causing you problems? 2. THERE IS NO NEED TO SHOUT BY TYPING IN ALL CAPS

Comment: Can you provide some sample input tables and the desired result, to help clarify what _exactly_ you want done?